# MQ C API - how to abort a waiting `MQGET` in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c, ibm-mq

I'm using the MQ C API in a multithreaded application, where multiple worker threads are processing incoming messages each from its own queue by calling `MQGET` in a loop (with `MQGMO_WAIT` set and a wait interval of `MQWI_UNLIMITED`).

It works but I can't find a clean way to shut down the worker threads. If I call `MQDISC` or `MQCLOSE` in another thread, it blocks whenever there is an outstanding `MQGET` call.

For now my best solution is to use a finite wait interval of `5000` instead of `MQWI_UNLIMITED`, this way `MQGET` calls return every 5 second, giving the app the chance to shutdown. But this solution is less efficient (worker threads wake up every 5 seconds), and it takes the app up to 5 seconds to shut down.

Terminating the threads using native OS API does not sound like a good solution.

So the question is - is there any way to cleanly abort a waiting `MQGET` when the wait interval is `MQWI_UNLIMITED`?

OS is Windows Server 2012 x64, MQ server version is 7.0.0.19.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two answers already given are good options, and I have a third to add, so here's the full list.

- You are on V7 as a mimumum so you can use the callback mechanism, MQCB, and a call-back function, then you can use MQCTL to suspend or stop the connection.
- Either use an admin command, or on another thread use MQSET call, to change the queue to GET(DISABLED), which will wake up the MQGET-wait with MQRC_GET_INHIBITED.
- From another thread MQPUT(1) a message to the queue the MQGET is waiting on. Ensure your getting code understands that the format/content of this message means "time to end the app".

All are equally valid, but require varying degrees of change to your current application, and only you can know which will be easiest in your code.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a sample application for MQCB?

Comment: Yes, amqscbf0.c in the Tools\c\Samples directory

Answer (score 2):

Use [MQCallBack](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.5.0/com.ibm.mq.mon.doc/q037660_.htm) call rather than MQGET.

Answer (score 1):

One option is if you disable getting from the queue (i.e. ALTER QLOCAL(xxx) GET(DISABLED)), any waiting getters will be immediately thrown out with a reason of MQRC_GET_INHIBITED.